# Show that $\nabla\Delta = E$.

Tags: numerical-methods

My assignment asks me to prove that
$$\nabla\Delta = E.$$
I was taught that
\begin{align*}
\nabla f(x) &= f(x) - f(x-h) \\
\Delta f(x) &= f(x+h) - f(x) \\
E f(x) &= f(x+h)  
\end{align*}
I was taught to show equality assuming we have a function $f(x)$, so I essentially plugged the above part into the identity that has to be proven. I can't seem to do it though. How to prove this?

Comment: Let $g(x)=\Delta f(x)=f(x+h)-f(x)$. Now apply $\nabla$ to $g(x)$, and then write out the result in terms of $f$.

Comment: Wouldn't that end up as 

    f(x+h) - 2f(x) + f(x-h) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have found $\nabla\Delta\ne E$, since 
\begin{align*}
\nabla\Delta f(x) &= \nabla(f(x+h)-f(x)) \\
&= \nabla f(x+h) - \nabla f(x) \\
&= (f(x+h)-f(x)) - (f(x)-f(x-h)) \\
&= f(x+h) - 2f(x) + f(x-h) \\
&\ne f(x+h).
\end{align*}
It is true that $\nabla\Delta = \Delta\nabla = \delta^2$, where 
$\delta f(x) = f(x+h/2)-f(x-h/2)$ is the central difference.

Comment: Ok. Glad to know I was not hopelessly lost.

Comment: Intuitively, for small $h$, $\nabla\Delta$, $\nabla^2$, and $\Delta^2$ are all proportional to the second derivative operator. See the discussion [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/146504/26872), for example.