# Is it possible to convert a higher order difference equation to a system of lower order difference equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

I know this is possible for differential equations. But is there a similar result for difference equations?

So I was thinking of going from a higher order difference equation describing a single sequence to a system of first order equation describing multiple sequences.

Answer (score 0):

It seems yes. Consider the second order system $u_{n+1} = u_n+u_{n-1}$ (i.e. Fibonacci).

Define $k_n = u_{n-1}$.

This gives two sequences $u_n$ and $k_n$.
And the system of first order equations governing these is 
$u_{n+1} = u_n + k_n$ and $k_{n+1} = u_n$.

So indeed we see a similar result.