# Relation between differential equations and difference equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

While going over problems in differential equations and difference equations, I realized that most of the techniques that we use to solve them are very similar. This has led me to wonder - is there a deeper theory that unifies both of them?

I tried to look around, and all that I could find is something called Time-Scale Calculus. How successful is this theory, and are there any other theories that try to unify Differential and Difference Equations?

(PS: By successful, I mean that whether it has been able to explain why exactly Difference and Differential Equations have similar methods of solving them, and also what exactly differentiates them)

Comment: Good observation. They also share characteristic equation as a method for solving

Comment: Please see https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-differential-equations-and-difference-equations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Links between difference and differential equations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145523/links-between-difference-and-differential-equations)